# How do you setup a Google Tag trigger for all links under a drop down menu?

Tags: html, jquery, css, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to add triggers to a website I can't edit the HTML or CSS on.

I need it to fire on the links under the SERVICE & PARTS drop-down-menu.

**Part 1.** trying to get all web links under the word "Service" to fire without having to make a trigger for each one.

**Part 2.** Trying to get all web links under the word "Parts" to fire without having to make a trigger for each one.

**Part 3.** I'm trying to set this up so when new web links are added to these drop-downs it will always trigger.

I have attempted to try and trigger them with conditions of "matches CSS selector" but, both of the CSS <ul drop-downs are the same. The only unique way I see to separate them is by having the trigger use the `<li class="ddc-span4"` and only fire if the <h4 tag has the word "Service" or "Parts" to separate these links from each other.
[image]
[image]

```
<h4 rold="heading aria-level"3">Service</h4>
<h4 rold="heading aria-level"3">Parts</h4>
```

I have attempted to create a User-Defined Variable following this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=26JfSV_LUzA

However, when I run the `google_tag_manager[“GTM-XXXX”].dataLayer.get("gtm.element")` in the console it comes back with "undefined" even though it shows content in the data layer.

Any guidance with what the best direction would be to accomplish this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways of doing this. I would first try, a link trigger or a click trigger.

The rule would be:

Click Element -  matches CSS selector  - .dropdown-menu .ddc-span4 a

if you want it to fire on the header2 only

#template-header-2 .dropdown-menu .ddc-span4 a

To check the header:

I would create a separate CJS variable using JQuery code that returns the header. Which can then be added to the event label/Category/Action or checked when firing the trigger.

The JQuery would be something like:

```
function() {
  return jQuery({{Click Element}}).closest(".ddc-span4").children("h4").text();
}
```